# xcode multiple storyboards for different sizes of device

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, storyboard

I'm making an app, but auto-layout isn't enough to make the screen look beautiful in all devices (for example, in iPhone 7 it looks ok, but in iPhone SE it doesn't).

I want to have a lot of storyboards, each of them should be the same, but without any auto-layout constraint and each of them will fit it's own device size (for example, one storyboard for iPhone 7, another for iPad, etc.)

How can I do this?

The first step I can think is to create a new storyboard (for iPhone SE for example) and connect the actions and the outlets to its codes, but I don't know if it will bring out some kind of conflict (because there is a storyboard who has this connections already). After this, I saw I had to do some things at AppDelegate (in order to associate each storyboard to a different device type) but it seemed strange to me...

I've been searching for it for a while and all answers I found seemed to be deprecated or different from what I'm searching for.

Thanks.

Comment: all i can say is that it is  not a good idea. Auto layout helps you develop your app for different devices if used properly.

Comment: well, I can use auto-layout quite well but it won't help a lot in this case, so I'd rather spend my time doing storyboards that will work for sure than making miracles at auto-layout (I wasted good time making the layout constraints but there are some situations that couldn't be helped...)

Comment: @Dc CoO i never created different storyboard so i am not sure about this but it seems like a good thing if worked.

Comment: @DcCoO : Why not use the size classes in storyboard to create various designs while using same storyboard :) second : Autolayouts are not miracle they are simple mathematical expressions, if you are aware of basic maths it you are good to go :)

Comment: Imagine you have your screen, in the top and in the bottom you have 2 rectangles and between them you have something like a square that fits the space left in screen. In iPhone 7 the square is OK (it must fit all screen left) but in other device the image distorts, so I need to load another image anyway cos I can't keep it (as I need to fill the rest of screen anyway). Auto-layout won't make the job and I don't wanna do this by code as it would be dirty code. Maths is not the problem